# If n is a positive Integer,then $43^{5n}-21^{5n}$ is always divisible by?

Tags: number-theory

If $n$ is a positive Integer,then $43^{5n}-21^{5n}$ is always divisible by

options:

a)$11\quad$   b)$18\quad$  c)$25\quad$   d)$64$

MyApproach:

I am not able to think how to solve this problem but.

I did $43^{5n}-21^{5n}=a^n-b^n$ where a=$43^5$ and b=$21^5$

So, $a^n-b^n/a-b$ whether $n$ is odd or even it is always divisible by $a-b$

I am not getting anywhere to the result

> Can anyone guide me how to solve the problem?

Comment: Hint: $a - b = 22 = 2\cdot 11$

Comment: Ans  will be 11 thank u

Answer (score 2):

it is divisible by 22 and hence 11.

Answer (score 2):

You say $43^k-21^k$ is always divisible by $42-21=22$.  You are very close.  What are the factors of $22?$